# Cucumber step definitions file unable to use keyword puts which is overridden in a ruby class in the same project

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

I have a step definition file which has the following line

```
puts "Beginning step execution"
```

In a seperate file (Not a ruby class) called helper.rb I have overidden puts so I can output the puts with a timestamp which looks like this

```
def puts(o)
  timenow = Time.now
  if o.is_a? Array
    msg = timenow.to_s+" OUT: "+o.to_s
  else
    msg = timenow.to_s+" OUT: "+o
  end
  super(msg.black)
end
```

The error I am getting is

> 2015-06-30 14:44:59 +0100 OUT: Error: undefined method <<' for nil:NilClass 2015-06-30 14:44:59 +0100 OUT: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2/lib/gherkin/formatter/json_formatter.rb:89:inwrite'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/formatter/gherkin_formatter_adapter.rb:166:in puts' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:181:inblock in send_to_all'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:179:in each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:179:insend_to_all'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:173:in broadcast' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:154:inputs'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/user_interface.rb:14:in puts' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_world.rb:107:inputs'
>   /Users/jenkins/workspace/TEST-regression-test_trial_mini/automation/ios/features/support/hooks.rb:104:in block in ' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:ininstance_exec'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in block in cucumber_instance_exec' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:69:incucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in cucumber_instance_exec' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_hook.rb:14:ininvoke'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:114:in invoke' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:102:inblock in execute_before'

This method for printing errors works fine

```
 def pute(o)
  timenow = Time.now
  if o.is_a? Array
    msg = timenow.to_s+" OUT: "+o.to_s
  else
    msg = timenow.to_s+" OUT: "+o
  end
  Kernel.puts(msg.red)
end
```

I thought it might be a problem with super but this method for printing using warn instead of puts works fine also

```
def warn(o)
  p "entered warn in gui_helper"
  timenow = Time.now
  if o.is_a? Array
    msg = timenow.to_s+" OUT: "+o.to_s
  else
    msg = timenow.to_s+" OUT: "+o
  end
  super(msg.black)
end
```

We have had this code for a long time and this just starting happening all of sudden a few days ago and it seems to only affect some of my machines. I have compared the versions of cucumber, ruby, gherkin and other key gems we are using and there is no difference. Calling the puts method in a ruby class in the same project works fine. It seems the problem is that using the keyword PUTS specifically in a step definition file has stopped working because Gherkin thinks the text passed in the write method is nil? Anyone any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: You have the time and the word `OUT` in your error message... looks like your `puts` override is working fine. Something is calling `puts` with those strings after an unrelated error?

Comment: The code that outputs the error/backtrace is not PUTS but another custom overridden method in our helper class called PUTE which I included above as an example of one that works. So yes the overriding is working fine for every case except when the method name is PUTS?? I can fix this easy enough but I will have to refactor a lot of my step definition files. I don't want to do that until I can understand why this is seemingly happening out of the blue and only on some machines?